# Reviewer/Steward badges showing twice on queue stats pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, user-interface

In the right-hand bar, the Reviewer and Steward badges are listed twice. This doesn't happen for Custodian badges.

Once showing I've achieved them, and once showing a negative value of the number of reviews required to meet the threshold.

[image]

In Triage, where I haven't achieved a Steward badge, the Reviewer badge is shown twice, but Steward isn't shown at all.

[image]

Is this intentional? It doesn't seem right.

Comment: Well.. if you want a second Steward badge for First Posts, you'll just have to undo 48 reviews :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This issue was reported on the global Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348925/the-review-badge-progress-indicator-shows-a-badge-i-already-have), and has since been [fixed by Brian Nickel, a Stack Exchange developer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348957).

The bug was introduced by a typo in a pull request for a separate "dark mode" fix, which left a `<p>` tag unclosed.